# Dark matter "hair" flowing through the earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, dark-matter

Gary Prézeau of NASA's JPL has [done some calculations of how dark matter might be focussed by the Earth's gravitational field](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=4774) ([publication preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07009)), and the results show some remarkable *hairy* structure.

[image: Dark matter hair]

This article says that many streams of dark matter flow through the Earth and are focussed into the structures shown in the photo. Where do these particles come from? Is this a once through flow, or are the particles recycled back through the Earth's core endlessly? From where does the energy come to power the flow. And what are the forces that channel and control these "non interacting dark particles"?

Comment: I'm afraid your description of the behaviour of dark matter is wildly inaccurate, and as a result your question can't usefully be answered. All we can usefully say is not to believe everything you read on dodgy web sites.

Comment: Please google "prezeau nasa" to see NASA post about dark matter simulation.--thanks, bob

Comment: Hi Bob. Thanks for the info. I could edit your question to include a link to one or more of the related articles then vote to reopen, though I won't do this without your approval.

Comment: Hi John, Yes please do edit my question. I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Done! Have a look and check you're happy with the changes.

Comment: While the edits by John have improved the post, I just don't see how any of the questions follow from the article (except *maybe* the last one) or current understanding of dark matter as WIMPs.

Comment: there are some questionable elements to the [actual paper that this press-release discusses](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07009) - and the article doesn't seem to have passed peer-review (despite the press-release coming out, which is also strange).  Please take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix -- The article did pass peer review, and in the Astrophysical Journal no less:  http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/814/2/122/meta . That said, being accepted in a peer reviewed scientific journal is where science starts rather than ends. One should always take anything recently written, even in a peer-reviewed journal article, with a grain of salt or two.